# How do you calculate a new scale from two given variables and then find out the cronbach-alpha?

Tags: cronbachs-alpha

The question concerns two variables with scores from a personality test, Ptest1 and Ptest2 with values from 60 participants from each variable. So how I can convert these two variables into a new scale and then calculate Cronbachs-alpha?

Comment: I'm not convinced this is the right thing to do. What are you trying to do and why are you doing it this way?